# C# Marshaling C DLL struct bool

Tags: c#, c, dll, struct, boolean

i have some trouble with bool while Marshaling C DLL struct
this is code in C DLL

```
// cbool.h

#ifndef CBOOL_H
#define CBOOL_H

#define false         0
#define true          !false
typedef unsigned char boolean; /* false=0, otherwise true */

#endif


// test.h
#include "cbool.h"

typedef struct
{
    bool a;
    bool b;
  float c;

} BoolStruct;

extern BoolStruct BStruct;
__declspec(dllexport) void  GetBStruct  (BoolStruct* bs);
__declspec(dllexport) void  SetBStruct  (BoolStruct* bs);

// test.c
#include "test.h"

BoolStruct BStruct;
void    GetBStruct  (BoolStruct* bs)
{
*bs = BStruct;
}

void    SetBStruct  (BoolStruct* bs)
{
BStruct = *bs; 
}
```

and in C#

```
public struct BoolStruct
{
    public bool a;
    public bool b;
  public float c;

}

BoolStruct bs;

[DllImport(DLL_NAME, EntryPoint = "GetBStruct")]
public static extern void GetBStruct(ref BoolStruct bs);

[DllImport(DLL_NAME, EntryPoint = "SetBStruct")]
public static extern void SetBStruct(ref BoolStruct bs);


bs.a = true;
bs.c = 0.5F;

... set
...get
```

But with float type set and get values are correct, while when i set boll (e.g. true) i receive always false
Can you help me?

Comment: What packing is the C using for structs? Try different values if you don't know, by specifying , `[DllImport(DLL_NAME, EntryPoint = "GetBStruct", Pack=8)]` and also try Pack = 4, 2 and 1.

Comment: depending on the size of your *cbool* you could use *byte* or *int16* to match the c struct

Comment: You should specify the `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` for `BoolStruct`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct BoolStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool a;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool b;

    public float c;
}
```

[By default the `bool` is marshaled as an `Int32` in .NET.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2t3725f(v=vs.80).aspx)

And you should always specify the `StructLayout` when you do PInvoke (but note that for `struct` [it isn't necessary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind(v=vs.110).aspx): *To reduce layout-related problems associated with the Auto value, C#, Visual Basic, and C++ compilers specify Sequential layout for value types.*)

Ah and you forgot the `CallingConvention`: normally it is `Cdecl` for C functions:

```
[DllImport("CPlusPlusSide.dll", EntryPoint = "GetBStruct", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void GetBStruct(ref BoolStruct bs);

[DllImport("CPlusPlusSide.dll", EntryPoint = "SetBStruct", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void SetBStruct(ref BoolStruct bs);
```

(tested both x86 and x64)

Answer (score 0):

i try your codes and suggestions, but don't work...
I temporarily resolved by editing the file CBool

```
typedef int boolean; /* false=0, otherwise true */
```

and it work!
in another similar  case

```
typedef struct {

    // don't work!
    //char TestString[5];

    // work!
    int TestString[5];

} MyStruct;
```

and C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct MyStruct
{
  public MyStruct(uint i)
  {
     // ......
    TestString = new char[5];
  }

  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=5)]
  public char[] TestString;  

}
```

it seems that char and unsigned are the problems, or am I doing wrong somethin 'else, but do not know what